# Create web share with C# fails with no errors

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6, event-viewer

I want to create on a specific folder web share (on the IIS).
I don't have any errors in the logs yet the share is not created (code below). 
in the event viewer I see two "service control manager" errors

A. The World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).

B. The IIS Admin Service service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s).

This code works great on 3 other machines and I suspect it is environmental issue, help will be appreciated.

```
// create a web shared for the audio path
IISVirtualRoot vRoot = new IISVirtualRoot();
string errorOut;
string RootWeb = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root";
string inPhysicalDirectory =  Path.Combine(index.TargetDir, "WAVS_" + index.ID);
string VirtualDirectory =  "WAVS_" + index.ID;

vRoot.Create(RootWeb, inPhysicalDirectory, VirtualDirectory, out errorOut);
```

Comment: What is this `IISVirtualRoot` class? Are you using the `System.EnterpriseServices.Internal` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

yes I do, I use System.EnterpriseServices.Internal

Comment: Since this is a response to @Kev's comment, it would be more appropriate to make this a comment rather than an answer.